# Error en la ruta de un formulario

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tengo el siguiente error en rails al generar un formulario:

> No route matches {:action=>"elec_config", :controller=>"atoms"}
>   missing required keys: [:query_val]

Tengo un modelo llamado Atom con 3 campos en la base de datos y agrege un atributo en su clase de la siguiente manera:

```
    class Atom < ApplicationRecord
      def initialize(*args)
        @query_val = args[0]
      end
    end
```

Cree la siguiente ruta

```
get "/atoms/:query_val/elec_config", to: "atoms#elec_config", as: "elec_config"
```

para el metodo *elec_config* en el cual realizo lo siguiente:

```
def elec_config
  @atom = Atom.where("id = :id or atom_name = :atom_name or symbol = :symbol", { id: params[:query_val], atom_name: params[:query_val], symbol: params[:query_val]})
  render plain: @atom.inspect ##solo para saber que este respondiendo bien
end
```

y cuando genero el formulario para hacer la consulta me da el error ya mensionado.

Este es el formulario

```
<%= form_for :atom, elec_config_path do  |f|  %>
  <%= f.label :query_val %>
  <%= f.text_field :query_val %>
<% end %>
```

Le agradeceria mucho su ayuda. Gracias :)

Algo más: ¿cómo puedo acceder al campo "id" que me devuelve esto `@num = Atom.where("id = :id or atom_name = :atom_name or symbol = :symbol", { id: params[:query_val], atom_name: params[:query_val], symbol: params[:query_val]})` y convertirlo a fixnum?

Comment: Por favor realiza una pregunta a la vez, te recomiendo abrir una pregunta nueva para la segunda duda que planteas proporcionando el log de los parámetros recibidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al utilizar la ruta `/atoms/:query_val/elec_config` estás indicando que recibirás el valor de `query_val` como parte de la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
/atoms/valor_query_val/elec_config
```

Sin embargo en tu forma lo estás pasando como parámetro `POST`, no en la ruta, la cual recibe `nil` en su lugar.

Veo dos alternativas que podrías utilizar:

1. Modificar la ruta para que sea `/atoms/elec_config` y tu forma funcionará correctamente tal como está.
2. Utiliza un *link* en lugar de una forma donde, a través de *Javascript* puedas leer el valor de campo y pasarlo como variable al *helper* de rutas.

La primera opción es la más simple por lo que te recomendaría inclinarte por esa.

Comment: Ya funciono de la forma /atoms/elec_config pero funciono solo con POST y no con GET. Para hacerlo con GET tendria que hacerlo de la segunda manera que me recomendaste, cierto?

Comment: @LeonardoArellano Debería funcionar con GET (i.e. utilizando `method=“get”); la segunda opción sería con un `link_to` para poder armar la ruta en formato _REST_. ¿Cómo estás haciendo el envío GET?

Comment: @LeonardoArellano Si te ayudó la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma). :)

Comment: la ruta queda `get "/atoms/:query_val/elec_config", to: "atoms#elec_config", as: "elec_config"`

Comment: el javascript queda: `$(document).on "click", "a#btnBuscar", (e)->
  e.preventDefault();
  ruta = "/atoms/" +$("#query_val").val()+ "/elec_config"
  $("form#frmRetirar").attr('action', ruta).submit()`

Comment: @LeonardoArellano  ¿Y te sigue dando el mismo error?

Comment: No ya no, gracias, solo que la url queda asi **http://localhost:3000/atoms/88/elec_config?query_val=88** porque se pasa query_val como si fuera parametro? Es normal eso?

Comment: @LeonardoArellano Eso se debe a que estás utilizando una forma en lugar de un link; si quisieras evitar el envío del paràmetro lo mejor que puedes hacer es utilizar un link; si quieres usar una forma, entonces quita el input del envío en la forma (aunque lo más sencillo es evitar la forma y utilizar un link).

Comment: @LeonardoArellano la forma siempre va a envair todos los `input` que estén dentro de ella, sin importar si es POST o GET. Una opcion adicional al link (y creo que te gustaría más) es en el javascript hacer un `redirect` a la ruta que ya armaste en lugar de hacer el `submit`.

Comment: funciono perfecto con el `redirect`, muchas gracias